# Duplicate Name in Query String

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to use python to input a line of query string (you don’t know how many fields there are, and you don’t know whether there are repeated field names) and output the query string without repeated fields (the order of the fields does not change)?
Example:

Input: `username=peter&score=80&username=john`

Output: `username=john&score=80`

Comment: can you add code you have tried to write so far? Also if you call this "query string", does it mean is it a part of a web application? If so, what framework you use?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be like

```
query = "username=peter&score=80&username=john"
unique = {f[0]:f[1] for f in [field.split("=") for field in query.split("&")}]}
output= "&".join([f"{field}={value}" for field, value in unique.items()])
```

But, to be precise, this is a happy path solution. If the input formats has issues, this will fail. Its ideal to use a proper library to handle the query string. The uniqueness of fields are determined with the key alone here.